# Angular JS form values not binding to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" role="form" name="newCategoryForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div input-field>
          <input type="text" name="cat-name" id="cat-name"
                 ng-model="category.catname" required>
          <label>Nombre</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div input-field>
          <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="cat-description" id="cat-description" length="144"
                    ng-model="category.catdescription" ng-maxlength="144" required></textarea>
          <label>Descripción</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <h6>Imagen de Fondo</h6>
        <div class="file-field input-field">
          <div class="btn pink darken-2 waves-effect waves-light">
             <span>Archivo</span>
             <input type="file" name="cat-bgimg" id="cat-bgimg"
                    file-model="variable" ng-model="category.catimg">
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path" type="text" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large pink darken-2 waves-effect waves-light center-button" ng-disabled="newCategoryForm.$invalid">Crear Categoría</button>
</form>
```

And in my controller I have this:

```
angular.module('sccateringApp')
  .controller('newCategoryController', function (httpcalls, $scope) {
    var request = httpcalls;
    $scope.submitForm = function(){
      $scope.catinfo = $scope.category;
      console.log($scope.catinfo);
      console.log(this.category);
      console.log(newCategoryForm.category);
    }
  });
```

As you can see, the controller logs undefined for all three ways I'm trying to print out the contents of the form:

[image]

I'm very new to Angular and I'm very inexperienced. I'm using the documentation as a reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: try so `$scope.newCategoryForm.category`

Comment: or pass `category` object to submit `function` as argument

Comment: I tried this already, both still return undefined. :(

Comment: Can you post the whole html? Is your form inside the newCategoryController controller?

Comment: It's an HTML view, that's all the HTML inside that specific view. All the code from the controller is on the other code snippet.

Comment: where is `$scope.category` defined?

Comment: httpcalls is that async? Also why are you using $scope as second parameter in your controller factory function?

Comment: I put your code into a js fiddle and I'm getting values for you first 2 console.logs http://jsfiddle.net/mpg8x37s/

Comment: check out your developer console, are you seeing errors?

Comment: Are you calling your controller, my-controller="newCategoryController"

Comment: Cannot reproduce this at all ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/IDy2IiuXEQTvCcBqPqQ2?p=preview